# PHP Triggers JS Then Returns Data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

I have a team email form which matches email of the sender and receiver using only names. I want to add a js prompt so that someone not on the list could use their email to send a message. here's what I have

```
 else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>prompt('$otheremail');</script>";
    $otheremail = file_get_contents("otheremail.json");

    #$otheremail=$_POST['data'];
    $findat2= '@';
    $pos2=strpos($otheremail, $findat2);
    while ($pos2 == false) {
        $pos2 = 'enter a valid email';
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>prompt('$pos2' , '');</script>";
    }
}
mail($toaddress, $subject, $message, $headers);
$success=htmlspecialchars($_GET['to']);
$success=ucwords($success);
$valid= 'sent to' . ' ' . $success . ' ' . 'from a php server. Hit the back arrow' ;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$valid');</script>";
```

Heres the whole body

```
<?php  
    session_start();
    $name=htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']); 
    $name=trim($name);
    $name=ucwords($name);
    #talkes in the parameter of 'name' from html form then trims it and changes the  first letter to uppercase [tells the name of sender]
    $to=htmlspecialchars($_GET['to']);
    $to=trim($to);
    $to=ucwords($to);
    #takes in the parameter of 'to' from  html form then trims it and changes the  first letter to uppercase [tells the name of recipient]
    $from=htmlspecialchars($_GET['from']);
    $from=trim($from);
    #takes in the parameter of 'from' from html and trims it [tells the email of the sender]
    $message=htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']);
    $message=trim($message);
    #takes in the message content from the html form
    $fromsub=htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']);
    #takes in the parameter of 'name' from the html form and inserts it in the subject field of the email

    #below is where the email is formatted given the values from the html form

    $toaddress='merrimack.scioly@gmail.com';
    $subject=  $fromsub . ' ' . 'sent you a message';
    $headers = 'From: ' . $fromsub . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n";
    $mailcontent= 'Team Member: ' . $fromsub . "\r\n"
                  .'Email: ' . $from . "\r\n"
                  .'Message: '.$message. "\r\n";
    $fromaddress= 'From: ' . $from;

    mail($toaddress, $subject, $message);

    $nwc=str_word_count($to);
    #checks that word count of name is at least 2
    while ($nwc < 2) {
        $nwc = "Please enter a first and last name";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$nwc');</script>";
        exit;
    }
    #counts words in from sub
    $fswc=str_word_count($fromsub);
    #checks that fromsub word count is less at least two
    while ($fswc < 2) {
        $fswc = "Please enter a first and last name";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$fswc');</script>";
        exit;
    }

$passemail = htmlspecialchars($_GET['from']);
$findat   = '@';
$pos = strpos($passemail, $findat);
    while ($pos === false) {
$pos = "Enter a valid email";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$pos');</script>";
        exit;
    }
                            /*INDEX OF NAMES --- WILL EVENTUALLY BECOME AN SQL DATABASE ---  INDEX OF NAMES*/

if (strstr($to, 'Andrew Pitten')) {
$toaddress='gamegalaxy64@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Anna Correia')) {
    $toaddress='anna.correia99@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Bryanna Bergevin')) {
    $toaddress='bubblebeauty25@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Brianna Bergevin')) {
    $toaddress='bubblebeauty25@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Caroline Pitten')) {
    $toaddress='crpitten@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Jason Provencher')) {
    $toaddress='jtproven@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Jordan Provencher')) {
    $toaddress='jrproven@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Ryan Bobbit')) {
    $toaddress='rbobbit7@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Sean Sylvester')) {
    $toaddress='sean.sylvester1@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Max Goddard')) {
    $toaddress='max.goddard6@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'James Davis')) {
    $toaddress='James.Davis@merrimack.k12.nh.us';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Mr Davis')) {
    $toaddress='James.Davis@merrimack.k12.nh.us';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Mr. Davis')) {
    $toaddress='James.Davis@merrimack.k12.nh.us';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Mrs Corliss')) {
    $toaddress='maryalice.corliss@merrimack.k12.nh.us';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Mrs. Corliss')) {
    $toaddress='maryalice.corliss@merrimack.k12.nh.us';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Sean Muller')) {
    $toaddress='seanp.muller@merrimack.k12.nh.us';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Mr Muller')) {
    $toaddress='Sean.Muller@merrimack.k12.nh.us';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Mr. Muller')) {
    $toaddress='Sean.Muller@merrimack.k12.nh.us';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Josh Waxman')) {
    $toaddress='jwembo21@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Carissa Yim')) {
    $toaddress='carrisayim@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'John Pitten')) {
    $toaddress='John.pitten@tufts.edu';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Zev Sernik')) {
    $toaddress='zev.sernik@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'YG')) {
    $toaddress='jrproven@gmail.com';
}
elseif (strstr($to, 'Tech Support')) {
    $toaddress='merrimack.scioly@gmail.com';
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$otheremail');</script>";
    $otheremail=$_POST['data'];
    $findat2= '@';
    $pos2=strpos($otheremail, $findat2);
    while ($pos2 == false) {
        $pos2 = 'enter a valid email';
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>prompt('$pos2' , '');</script>";
    }
}

mail($toaddress, $subject, $message, $headers);
$success=htmlspecialchars($_GET['to']);
$success=ucwords($success);
$valid= 'sent to' . ' ' . $success . ' ' . 'from a php server. Hit the back arrow' ;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$valid');</script>";


/*
#=================#===============================================================#==============
|VARIABLE GLOSSARY|                     DEFINITON                                 |
#=================#===============================================================#==============
|$fromsub         |takes in from and puts it into email subject                   |
|$fswc            |counts the words in fromsub and makes sure its two words       |
|$name            |takes in the name of SENDER                                    |
|$nwc             |checks that the RECIPIENT is first and last name               | 
|$toaddress       |email address of RECIPIENT from the variable $to               |
|$to              |takes in 'to'                                                  |
|$subject         |email subject                                                  |
|$message         |takes in content from the field 'message'                      |
|$passeamail      |checks that email includes @                                   |
|$headers         |email header                                                   |
|$success         |lets the user know that they have succesfully sent the email   |
|$findat          |set the $passemail value to pos                                |
|$pos             |set the $passemail value to check for @                        |
|$valid           |pushes a javascript alert using $success as a field variable   |
#=================#===============================================================#===============
OTHER NOTES 

else echo "I do not recognize this person";
nl2br somehwere
*/
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be achieved through [jquery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), since php is executed on the server side it is always executed before the javascript and so you can't do it that easily.
Here's my suggestion (without [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)):

1. Create a new page(p1.php), send-mail.php, that simply receives the email
   parameters(to, from, message, ...) in either post or get and sends
   the email;
2. Use your current page as a form only to get the values and set your form like so `<form action = "p1.php" method = "post">` and then in that form display the inputs for the user to choose the email to send from.

Here's how to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), this is javascript:

**This could be a function triggered by a button click or other event...**

```
<script>
    function send_mail(to_email, message, headers){
        var from_email = prompt("Where from?");

        var form_data = {from:from_email ,to:to_email, message, headers};//add your own data

        $.ajax({
            url : "send-email-page.php",
            type: "POST",
            data : form_data ,
            success: function(data)
            {
                //data is what the send-email-page will echo
                //it could be a message for the user saying 'email sent'
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And you could have something like this in your php page:

```
<a href = "javascript: send_mail(<?php echo "$to,$message,$headers";?>)">Send from another address</a>
```

---

After editing my answer:

Once again, if you include JS in the php the JS will be printed to html but **it will not be executed untill all the php code has**

Perhaps it would be best for you to evaluater whether there is a valid name or not and, if not, print a new form with an input asking for the other name, and when this form is submited it calls itself(the php page) again with the same GET parameters except for the new name the user inserted, this way you are continuously asking for a valid email/name until you have one, if the name is valid then simply send the email and don't print the form.

Comment: So do I need to use a js email form now?

Comment: Because there's more code to this like it passes through different names and and then applies an email address to it

Comment: How do you pass those names to the page that generates the email addresses (get, post, ...)?

Comment: I added the entire code above so you can look at it. You enter in a name on the htmk form which calls the php form and then it replaces the fields with values from the html form. Since its php, i use inheritance to redefine the fields for the final email

Comment: so my html form currently does collect just values which php fiddles around with. What im trying to do is that when you enter your name and its not in the list, it prompts you with an option to enter in your own email. Could potentially become a registration system

Comment: I'm still reading but i think you wanted to do `mail($toaddress, $subject, $mailcontent, $headers);` instead of `mail($toaddress, $subject, $message);`